# Convert String path to File FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter, file, dart, firebase-storage

I have List containing paths like below

```
/storage/emulated/0/Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Images/IMG-20210623-WA0016.jpg
```

Converting it to file always returns false.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < tempLocations.length; i++) {
      print(tempLocations.length);

      File newFile = File(tempLocations[0]);
      if (await newFile.exists()) {
        print("true");
      } else {
        print("false");
      }
    }
```

How do i convert it to a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [flutter_absolute_path](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_absolute_path) to get the excat path

> A flutter plugin that finds the absolute path of a file in iOS or Android devices.

null safety version

```
flutter_absolute_path:
git:
url: https://github.com/kornperkus/flutter_absolute_path.git
```

```
     // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
      Future<void> init() async {
        /// uri can be of android scheme content or file
        /// for iOS PHAsset identifier is supported as well
    
        List<Asset> assets = await selectImagesFromGallery();
        List<File> files = [];
        for (Asset asset in assets) {
// asset.identifier replace with your path
          final filePath =
              await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(asset.identifier);
          files.add(File(filePath));
        }
    
        // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
        // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
        // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
        if (!mounted) return;
    
        setState(() {
          _files = files;
        });
      }
```

Comment: Yup i thought of using this but it doesn't supports null safety so even if I add it will throw me error while compiling

Comment: updated my answer with a null safety version

Comment: The plugin `flutter_absolute_path` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs

Comment: in the repo there is a PR with nullsafety and v2 embedding